# adding a new container to root

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.1, theme, xml

I'm trying to add a new container into root.
I've tried placing the code to `empty.xml`, `default.xml`, `1column.xml`.
I've checked with changing another element in the same file if the file is loaded and parsed.
But whatever I do I just can't add the container.
This is the code:

```
<referenceContainer name="root">
    <referenceContainer name="header.container" htmlId="header"/>
    <container name="header.container.mobile" as="header_container_mobile" label="Page Mobile Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlId="header_mobile" htmlClass="navbar navbar-fixed-top" after="header.container"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

So it will add the html id "header" to the "header.container" which appears as `<header ...>` in the page. (I have moved this container to root elsewhere).
But it doesn't add the container "header.container.mobile". (I have tried other names too)

How can I add the container?

Comment: I can't even add it into the core files. If I place it just right below the instantiation of `header.container` in the core file of Magento_Theme `htdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/1column.xml` it still does not appear, even though adding another class to the footer in the same file does appear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure a container needs some contents before it'll show up.

Comment: No, it shows up without anything in it, which is odd but i guess its just generating an element on the page no matter what.

Comment: Odd. I've always had to add *something* to get it to show up.

Comment: Maybe depends on the version? 2.0.1 vs 2.0.0 vs 2.1.2 ?? Not sure but seems to render without anything in it for me >_<

Comment: It doesn't render without content for me too. Boy what a headache. After adding a block into the container it shows up. I mean its a, what I call real, container defining itself with an html tag. Why wouldn't it show up without content?

Comment: Must be a 2.1 thing as that's what I've been using.

Comment: @andyjones What version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Im pretty sure you don't need to do it into 'root' how you have done it.

I would think it is like so.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="some.container" as="someContainer" label="Some Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="some-container" after="header.container" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Add this into:

> Vender/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Or for root it might be:

```
<container name="root">
        <container name="some.container" as="someContainer" label="Some Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="some-container" after="header.container" />
    </container>
```

Comment: This doesn't work and if it did I'm pretty sure it would add "header_mobile" into "header.container". But I want the new container below "header.container".

Comment: I misread what you put, that should now add a container after the header.container.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I have moved `header.container` to the root container, it is not in the `page.wrapper` anymore at that point.

Comment: Okay this is a bit of a guess, as i've not done that yet haha. Instead of using referencecontainer use <container name="root"> and drop the new container into that.